# Absorbing sets on a vector space

Tags: vector-spaces

The following definition for absorbing set is base in [here](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Barrelled_space). With this definition, is it true that finite intersection of absorbing sets is also absorbing?

Comment: Just in case you were interested in the result without proof, Wikipedia  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_set

states that the finite intersection of absorbing sets is indeed absorbing.

Comment: @Sujaan Kunalan. Yeah,  i can prove the said assertion by using the definition you mention. It seems that I have to prove that the two definitions are equivalent.